# bootstrap carousel issue in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title suggests I'm having a few issues with twitter's bootstrap carousel in IE7 and was hopping anyone could give me advice.

firstly I noticed the carousel doesn't slide in IE7 and after some reading I realized twitter were using css3 transitions for the slide effect and IE doesn't support this at all yet so I found a solution using jQuery animation that was written by "Barryvdh" from GitHub. here's the  link:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/3052/files

while this does solve the sliding issue, I am having now a different issue with IE 7... after the slide animation finishes all the images inside the slide disappear until I hover over one of the control arrows.

here I created a jsBin of the code so you could see the issue:
http://jsbin.com/ozaxib/1/edit

I would appreciate any help! thank you.

Comment: still haven't found a solution for this :( it is driving me nuts!
please help me I can't rest

Comment: for now I decided to drop the slide support for ie7 which is a shame but oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barryvdh from github gave this answer for the issue:

You can fix that with this line of css:

```
.carousel .item {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. But when I added the css changes in that changeset you have linked to, it worked for me!

Comment: I think it was fixed in a later revision. anyways I posted the solution now. thanks for reminding me about this question. :)